# How to create a distance slicer in PowerBI, is my formatting correct?

Tags: excel, powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, geocoding

Hello everyone I am a newbie at PowerBI and my data consists of x number of people and 18 locations.
I have X zipcodes and I geocoded everything so now I have actual numbers and everything is sorted but I am having trouble on the next steps.

My excel sheet currently looks like this and I think that's what causing the problem.

ZIPCODES location x         location y          location z         location....18
33333 (distance measured) (distance measured) (distance measured) (distance measured)
222222 (distance measured) (distance measured) (distance measured) (distance measured)
111111 (distance measured) (distance measured) (distance measured) (distance measured)
21121221
(last zip) (distance measured) (distance measured) (distance measured) (distance measured)

It was set up this way so I can do calculations as I have hundreds of thousand of zipcodes but only 18 locations that I want to compare to. Meaning I have millions of rows but only 19 columns for the 18 locations

How should the data be set up instead? I want to create a slicer and a number card at the very least. I can add a visual map later. Or is this okay and I am just not knowing what to do in PowerBI? Please be as specific as possible (literally just learning how to use this)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If all you're doing is measuring from your given 18 locations to other zipcodes, would you not want something simple like
(LocationID, ToZipCode, Distance)?

What did you want to do with the data?

Comment: also, You could create a dummy table with numbers from 1 to N (units of distance). Then use FILTER('Tablename',[Distance]<=SELECTEDVALUE(Dummytable[NumberOfUnits]) )

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.